# Modules function in Erlang

Tags: function, module, erlang

So, this here is part of a module I'm writing:

```
request(Pid, ListOfDocuments) when is_pid(Pid), is_list(ListOfDocuments) ->
io:format("We get here~n"),
case whereis(jdw_api) of
    undefined -> [no, api];
    ApiPid when is_pid(ApiPid) ->
        io:format("... and here~n"),
        % (1) Won't work: spawn(?MODULE, loop, [Pid, ListOfDocuments])
        % (2) Won't work, either: ?MODULE:loop(Pid, ListOfDocuments)
        loop(Pid, ListOfDocuments) % (3) and neither does this...
end.
```

... and so is this:

```
loop(Pid, Docs) when is_list(Docs), length(Docs) > 0 ->
H = hd(Docs),
T = tl(Docs),
io:format("... but not here...~w~n", H),
case ?MODE of
    sync ->
        Ref = make_ref(),
        jdw_api ! {self(), Ref, doc, H},
        Ans = loop_sync(Ref, [], []),
        Pid ! Ans,
        loop(Pid, T);
    async -> {error, 'async mode not implemented yet', ?FILE, ?LINE};
    _ -> {'?MODE must be either async or sync'}
end;
loop(Pid, Docs) -> io:format("Done with document list").
```

... but for some reason, the "loop" function never gets called. Neither of the three different ways makes the magic happen... Any pointers?

Comment: How do you mean "never gets called"?. Does nothing happen, or the process crashes, or what? The `H` vs `[H]` error mentioned by @archaelus would cause the process to crash and if it wasn't linked to anything then the crash would be silent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop function might get called, but the code you show above is only one clause of that function, and it will only run if called with a Pid and a non-empty list of documents. The other problem is your buggy call to `io:format("... but not here...~w~n", H)` which should be `io:format("... but not here...~w~n", [H])`. That call might be crashing the loop code. Without more source to work from and example arguments to `request/2` it's hard to tell.

Comment: The other clause is right below the block of code. It's just a formatting issue in the question. (There is no guard and it only does an io:format.) Good catch on the `H` vs `[H]` problem.

Comment: Yes, indeed, doing **[H]** instead of **H** solves the problem - Also, all three methods of calling 'loop' now works. Thanks!